# How can I prevent switching to a particular Git branch?

Tags: git

I work in a repo that has a `master` branch, and also a `main` branch from a `git subtree` remote that I *never want to switch to*.

Unfortunately, because of the recent misguided move from `master` to `main` I also work in some other repos that use `main` as their branch name. So sometimes I forget and `git switch main` in the first repo. It's quite annoying because it replaces *all* the files in the repo (because of how `git subtree` works) and is quite slow.

Is there any way I can make `git switch main` not work *only for that repo*.

I guess Git doesn't have that feature but can I do some clever Bash alias?

Comment: Why not rename the branch to something you won't keep switching to by mistake? What is the purpose of this branch?

Comment: Yes you can! By using `includeIf` in your `.gitconfig`, you can specify _another_ `.gitconfig` for just this one repo. That other `.gitconfig` can contain your alias. (I use this feature to give myself different emails for different repos, but there is no reason why the second `.gitconfig` should not inject an additional alias.)

Comment: Also, I am curious about why you have a branch that you would never want to switch to. What is the point of that?

Comment: I said in the question. It's from a `git subtree` remote. It's not my branch; I can't rename it. Thanks for the suggestion @matt!

Comment: Although... how do I use an alias to prevent this? I don't think git's aliases are powerful enough. Maybe I can use a branch alias and just alias `main` to `master`.

Comment: _Who_ said renaming a branch wouldn't cause issues? Sounds like a strawman rant to me. :)

Comment: [Here's an example](https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/jtrx1k/announcement_posts_complaining_about_renaming/) "This change hurts nobody" (backtracked of course). You can probably dig through Twitter if you want to find more examples. It's a bit tricky to find things there from years ago though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not ideal, but you can alias `main` to `master` like this:

```
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/main refs/heads/master
```

It only applies to the current repo. I say it's not ideal because I've run into issues in the past using this approach. I can't remember the details but it's not 100% reliable.

I did also try making `main` be an invalid ref, but unfortunately if you do git just ignores it and acts as if it doesn't exist.